# Nginx - Need regex to append a parameter to url

Tags: regex, nginx

I have been stuck on a regex. I want to append `foo=1` to all URLs.

For a URL like:

```
www.xyz.com/
Rewrite:
www.xyz.com/?foo=1
```

For a URL like:

```
www.xyz.com/?abc=2
Rewrite:
www.xyz.com/?abc=2&foo=1
```

Answer (score 3):

try putting your variable before the args,

```
location /whatever {
    try_files $uri /index.php?foo=1&$args;
}
```

This way if args are empty you'll have `foo`, if not it will be appended.
Putting $args first might make your request end up looking like this

```
www.xyz.com/?&foo=1
```

because `$args` were first and they were empty, and I'm not sure if that will be handled correctly or not.

Mind also that if you explicitly define `foo` the value you entered will be overwritten by nginx.

```
www.xyz.com/?foo=new_value&foo=1
```

`foo=1` will overwrite the new value, if you want to protect that value putting `$args` at the end will help you do that.

Answer (score 0):

The one below is for your first url

```
([w]{3}\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4}|[a-zA-Z]{2}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4}\.[a-zA-Z]{2}))/?
```

This is for the second url

```
([w]{3}\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4}|[a-zA-Z]{2}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4}\.[a-zA-Z]{2}))/?(\?\S*=\S*)
```

Answer (score -1):

In Nginx this is **not** achieved by `rewrite`, as it operates only on the path portion of the URI. Instead you have to modify the `$args` variable:

```
set $args $args&foo=1
```

Comment: if `$args` is empty, this is a problem